# Flash-Adding Symbol to Stage in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, object, adobe

I am trying to add a symbol from my library to the stage. For some reason, when I run the code, no objects are appearing on the stage but I am not getting any errors either. I can't provide all of the code because its VERY long, but I'll provide enough for anyone reading to get a good idea of what I'm trying to do.

Basically, the main as3 file starts like this:

package  {

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class NewFrogMod extends MovieClip 

{

        var oneHit:Boolean;
        var twoHit:Boolean;
        var threeHit:Boolean;
        var fourHit:Boolean;
        var fiveHit:Boolean;
        var sixHit:Boolean;
        var sevenHit:Boolean;
        var eightHit:Boolean;
        var nineHit:Boolean;
        var tenHit:Boolean;
        var elevenHit:Boolean;
        var twelveHit:Boolean; 
        var thirteenHit:Boolean; 
        var fourteenHit:Boolean; 

        var score:uint;


        var frog1:Frog;
        var truck1:Truck;
        var truck2:Truck;
        var truck3:Truck;
        var car1:Car;
        var car2:Car;
        var log1:Logs;
        var log2:Logs;
        var log3:Logs;
        var log4:Logs;
        var turtle1:Turtles;
        var turtle2:Turtles;
        var z1:Zfrog;
        var z2:Zfrog;
        var z3:Zfrog;
        var z4:Zfrog;
        var z5:Zfrog;


    public function NewFrogMod()

    {

    var score = 0;


    frog1 = new Frog();
    truck1 = new Truck();
    truck2= new Truck();
    truck3 = new Truck();
    car1 = new Car();
    car2 = new Car();
    log1 = new Logs();
    log2 = new Logs();
    log3 = new Logs();
    log4 = new Logs();
    turtle1 = new Turtles();
    turtle2 = new Turtles();
    z1 = new Zfrog();
    z2 = new Zfrog();
    z3 = new Zfrog();
    z4 = new Zfrog();
    z5 = new Zfrog();


    addChild(frog1);
    addChild(truck1);
    addChild(truck2);
    addChild(car1);
    addChild(car2);
    addChild(log1);
    addChild(log2);
    addChild(log3);
    addChild(turtle1);
    addChild(turtle2);
    addChild(z1);
    addChild(z2);
    addChild(z3);
    addChild(z4);
    addChild(z5);

    frog1.x = 238;
    frog1.y = 373;

    truck1.x = 0;
    truck1.y = 252;

    truck2.x = 205;
    truck2.y = 252;

    car1.x = 82;
    car1.y = 175;

    car2.x = 363;
    car2.y = 175;

    log1.x = 22;
    log1.y = 51;

    log2.x = 355;
    log2.y = 51;

    log3.x = 43;
    log3.y = 102;

    log4.x = 292;
    log4.y = 102;


    turtle1.x = 241;
    turtle1.y = 81;

    turtle2.x = 508;
    turtle2.y = 125;

    z1.x = 200;
    z1.y = 250;

    z2.x = 300;
    z2.y = 350;

    z3.x = 100;
    z3.y = 150;

    z4.x = 100;
    z4.y = 250;

    z5.x = 200;
    z5.y = 150;
```

Then there's a bunch more after that....

Now, to give you an idea of how I'm setting up the objects, here is the code for some of them:

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Car extends NewFrogMod{

    public function Car() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Enter4);
    }
    function Enter4(event:Event):void
    {
        this.x += 3;

    }
}
```

}

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Truck extends NewFrogMod{

    public function Truck() 
        {

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Enter5);
        }
    function Enter5(event:Event):void {

        if(this.hitTestObject(frog1))
           {
                health1.width -= 5;   


            }
    }


}
```

}

I've tried extending MovieClip with these files as well and that doesn't work either. Any hep is GREATLY aqppreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the parent class NewFrogMod which adds the movieclip, has itself been added to the stage.

Also ensure that each library symbol, eg. Truck, has been linked to its class:

1. Right-click the symbol in the library and choose Properties from the menu.
2. Check the box 'Export for ActionScript'.
3. In the Class field, enter the full class path of your Truck class (simply 'Truck' in your case). The base field class can be ignored as your Truck class already extends MovieClip.

Alternatively, specify NewFrogMod as the document class of the main timeline:

1. Left-click an empty part of the stage, go to the Properties inspector and enter NewFrogMod into the Class field.

Comment: When I try to add the parent class (NewFrogMod) to the stage, the swf stops working.

Comment: NewFrogMod contains the child movieclips so it needs to be added to the stage. Or you could specify NewFrogMod as the document class of the main timeline.

Answer (score 0):

i think it may be that you added the objects before you specified the location. try moving the addChild functions below the x and y coordinates.